# how to extract a specific lines and columns from a file and save it in another file

Tags: python, file, line, extract

I have a huge file and I need to extract specific rows and columns, then save them in an output file. I have around 1000 file so I want to do the same for all the files then I will have 1000 new files containing the data I want. I am really beginner in python and I find difficulties to do it.

I have tried read the file and save all lines in a list, but i could't do more.

```
Cycle 3 Down - 20_3.2_10_100_1                                                  
units of measure: atoms / barn-cm                                             
time (years)   

nuclide   1.000E-02 3.000E-02 1.000E-01 3.000E-01 1.000E+00 3.000E+00 1.000E+01

--------  --------- --------- --------- --------- --------- --------- --------- 

 ag109   9.917E-07 9.917E-07 9.917E-07 9.917E-07 9.917E-07 9.917E-07 9.917E-07
 am241   1.301E-07 1.389E-07 1.695E-07 2.565E-07 5.540E-07 1.349E-06 3.577E-06
 am243   8.760E-08 8.760E-08 8.760E-08 8.760E-08 8.759E-08 8.757E-08 8.752E-08
 cs133   2.083E-05 2.101E-05 2.112E-05 2.112E-05 2.112E-05 2.112E-05 2.112E-05
 eu151   4.979E-10 5.579E-10 7.679E-10 1.367E-09 3.458E-09 9.368E-09 2.935E-08
 eu153   1.128E-06 1.132E-06 1.132E-06 1.132E-06 1.132E-06 1.132E-06 1.132E-06
 gd155   4.398E-10 5.831E-10 1.081E-09 2.477E-09 7.048E-09 1.778E-08 3.786E-08
 mo95    1.317E-05 1.351E-05 1.466E-05 1.716E-05 1.960E-05 1.979E-05 1.979E-05
 nd143   1.563E-05 1.587E-05 1.626E-05 1.641E-05 1.641E-05 1.641E-05 1.641E-05
 nd145   1.181E-05 1.181E-05 1.181E-05 1.181E-05 1.181E-05 1.181E-05 1.181E-05
 np237   2.898E-06 2.944E-06 2.982E-06 2.985E-06 2.986E-06 2.989E-06 3.017E-06
```

This is the part of the file that I want to save. I want to save the nuclide name and the last column values.

```
nuclide=[]
with open ('filename.txt','r') as myfile:
     for line in myfile:
         nuclide.append(line)
     print(nuclide[4900]).find("ag109"))
```

I should have a list containing a nuclide symbol with the last column value

Comment: What is the significance of the quantity 4900?  Why do you expect to be extracting the last column?  Your find call, even if it is operating on a valid entry, is just going to return an index value into the line of text.  So you just want to obtain the last column value for a single row, or do you want to process all of the rows and produce another table with just the first and last columns?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to read the data you show, extract just the data lines, parse them to extract the first and last columns, and then write just the first and last columns to a file, here's how you can do that:

```
import re

with open("/tmp/input.txt") as ifh:
    with open("/tmp/output.txt", "w") as ofh:
        while True:
            line = ifh.readline()
            if not line:
                break
            columns = re.split(r"\s+", line.strip())
            if len(columns) == 8 and  columns[0] != 'nuclide' and columns[0][0] != '-':
                ofh.write("{} {}\n".format(columns[0], columns[7]))
```

I tried to be super forgiving of exactly what was at the beginning of the file. Here's the output from taking the data you give in your question, pasting into a file as is with all the stuff at the top, and then running this program over it.

/tmp/output.txt:

```
ag109 9.917E-07
am241 3.577E-06
am243 8.752E-08
cs133 2.112E-05
eu151 2.935E-08
eu153 1.132E-06
gd155 3.786E-08
mo95 1.979E-05
nd143 1.641E-05
nd145 1.181E-05
np237 3.017E-06
```

This should be able to handle very large files, as I don't read the whole file into memory, but rather read and write lines one by one.

Comment: Thank you, i tried using your module, its working but the output is not only the part i need, it writes every columns[0] and columns[7] from the beginning of the file 
i don't know why the module does not follow the condition of (if len(columns) == 8 and  columns[0] != 'nuclide' and columns[0][0] != '-':)